# Eidolon Damage scaling

Tags: damage, pathfinder-2e, summoner, eidolon

Eidolons do 1d8 damage with their attacks, and it does not seem to scale. I guess it cannot remain this low at 20th level, but I could not find anything, neither in the Summoner nor in the Eidolon section of Secrets of Magic. I even checked the Summoner feats for "unarmed".

How does it scale?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Eidolons benefit from your Handwraps of Mighty blows

Unlike Animal Companions, Eidolons are not improved via feats.
They get better protection and damage from your gear ([Secrets of Magic p53, Gear and Your Eidolon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=18)):

> Your eidolon's link to you means it can benefit from certain magic items invested by you.
> Your eidolon's Strikes benefit from the fundamental and property runes on your handwraps of mighty blows. Alternatively, you can Invest a magic weapon (even though magic weapons can't normally be Invested) to share its fundamental and property runes with your eidolon. You share these benefits only while you're holding the weapon, and you can have no more than one weapon invested in this way at a time